# Why is double declared in this manner?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++,have code with double declared like this

```
constexpr double population_initiale(7.0);
double population(population_initiale);
```

Why not

```
double population=0;
```

What is the difference?

Comment: There's no difference. It's equivalent.

Comment: Aside that fact that one is 7 and the other is 0, that is.

Comment: You probably meant `double population=7.0;` didn't you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One has value `7.0`; the other has value `0.0`.

Also, in the first case, you could use `population_initiale` somewhere else too, if you liked. It's not clear from your question whether that's useful in your case. In general, though, it looks like someone was trying to avoid "[magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))" … and possibly went a little over-the-top in the process.

Comment: To be fair, we can't tell if `population_initale` is used later on.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I said that.